# What to use Canvas/Surfaceview or OpenGL

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, surfaceview

I know this question has been asked too many times here, but all the time it is related to either 2D or 3D game.

I am trying to create an application like [Skitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.skitch&hl=en), and want to know either to use Opengl or stick with Canvas, Surface view.

Which is best to use Performance wise.

Comment: If your primary concern is raw performance, using OpenGL ES directly is the best approach.  However... I haven't used Skitch, but looking at the play store entry I'm not sure why you'd need to be on the bleeding edge of graphics rendering performance.  Seems like the ease of rendering fonts will be of more value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum performance = OpenGL

Easy implementation & more than average performance = SurfaceView

I'm not providing any benchmark tests here, but that's based on own experience. Sometimes even OpenGL may have performance problems)

Remember - [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)